# Websphere Application Server 7 server adapter for Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere-7, eclipse-luna

I'm using **Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)** and I have **WAS 8.5.5** server adapter installed. The server and the apps deployed in it work fine.

The production setup however is using **WAS 7**, hence, I want the Luna to include WAS 7 but whenever I try to 'download additional server adapter', I don't see any relevant options except **WASCE server adapter**(for versions v1.x and v2.x) which I'm not sure will include the WAS 7 server adapter. I want to use both the versions (7.x and 8.5.x) via Eclipse.

How shall I proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [WebSphere Developer Tools for Luna](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Luna), you will have adapter for 8.5, 8.0, 7.0 and WebSphere Liberty there.

Comment: Heck ! I had installed this two months ago but had unchecked the option for V7.x during the installation. Now I simply updated it to include the 7.x version.

Comment: @KaliyugAntagonist That's why I was a bit surprised, how you managed to have only one, since by default you get all versions  ;-).